# Abstract base class is not enforcing function implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, python-3.4

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class AbstractBase(object):
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

  @abstractmethod
  def must_implement_this_method(self):
      raise NotImplementedError()

class ConcreteClass(AbstractBase):

   def extra_function(self):
       print('hello')

   # def must_implement_this_method(self):
     # print("Concrete implementation")


d = ConcreteClass()  # no error
d.extra_function()
```

I'm on Python 3.4. I want to define an abstract base class that defines somes functions that need to be implemented by it's subclassses. But Python doesn't raise a NotImplementedError when the subclass does not implement the function...

Comment: What happens when you call `d.must_implement_this_method()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The syntax** for the declaration of *metaclasses* **has changed in Python 3**. Instead of the `__metaclass__` field, **Python 3 uses a *keyword argument*** in the *base-class list*:

```
import abc

class AbstractBase(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def must_implement_this_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Calling `d = ConcreteClass()` will **raise an exception** now, **because a *metaclass* derived from `ABCMeta` can not be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are *overridden*** (For more information see [`@abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)):

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcreteClass with abstract methods
must_implement_this_method
```

Hope this helps :)